# Between Oksendal and Karatzas & Shreve books

Tags: stochastic-processes, self-learning, book-recommendation

I finished Oksendal "SDE , an introduction with applications" , did most of the exercises (not all with success, but I read the solutions for those); my next project would be to read the Karatzas & Shreve  "Brownian motion and stochastic calculus".
After perusing the first pages, it seems to me that there is a major knowledge gap between both.

Would anyone suggest a book to read after Oksendal, in order to start Karatzas & Shreve with a decent chance to make sense of it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at "Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes" by Schilling & Partzsch or "Continuous Martingales and Brownian motion" by Revuz & Yor.

Comment: Revuz & Yor's book is more difficult than Karatzas & Shereve's book. Karatzas & Shereve's book is well written with adequate details and contains very few mistakes.